# How to convert BLOB file(s) as image in Server with Php?

Tags: php, google-chrome-extension, server, blob

I'm trying to save a screenshot converted into a blob to MySQL server. The blob is not getting saved into the server using the PHP code seen below. I have tried POST, PUT and GET. This is not a file upload but blob from a screenshot of the user's desktop.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('screenshot');
canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
var url='http://20four7va.co/api/SaveScreenshotImg.php';
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("POST", url, true);
oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
// Uploaded.
};  
oReq.send(blob);
}, "image/jpeg", 0.5);  

<?php

$image= $_POST['bl'];
$eid= $_POST['i'];

$conn = new mysqli('example.com','asdasd','dsgfhd','dgfhgsdf');

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$query = "UPDATE TR_SCREENSHOTS SET SCRN_SHOT = '".$image."' WHERE RECORD_ID =".$eid."";

if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {    
echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

I checked some references here regarding BLOB to the server but it's not fulfilling the purpose. I am expecting to save the BLOB as an image from a screenshot.

Comment: Do not post questions with valid passwords! How does your `bl` looks like? Do you have `$eid` in database, is it numeric? If not, you must enclose it in quotes? Why not using prepared statement? Visiting `http://20four7va.co/api/SaveScreenshotImg.php` would sai `Record updated successfully` so I think you have deeper problem

Answer (score 0):

Please use prepared statements for your queries, this will cause big problems for your code, however, to be more specific to your question, you need to get the contents of the blob using php:input

```
$file=(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

Now i am hoping you fix your code to use better statements, but this is how you would write it ,if you did not fix your error prone code

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('screenshot');
canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
var url='http://20four7va.co/api/SaveScreenshotImg.php';
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("POST", url, true);
oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
// Uploaded.
};  
oReq.send(blob);
}, "image/jpeg", 0.5);  

<?php
//Get image from request here
$image=file_get_contents('php://input');
$eid= $_POST['i'];

$conn = new mysqli('example.com','asdasd','dsgfhd','dgfhgsdf');

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
if($image){
  $query = "UPDATE TR_SCREENSHOTS SET SCRN_SHOT = '".$image."' WHERE RECORD_ID 
   =".$eid."";
 }
 else{
     //handle the scenario that the image does not exist or was not sent
 }


if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {    
echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

?>
```